# Vectorized code to iterate one panda dataframe and compare values to a second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `DataFrames`:

```
df_1:

name value
foo  5
baz  5

df_2:

name value1 value2
foo  3      7
bar  12     15
baz  2      3
fuz  4      9
```

And I need to compare each row in `df_1` to each row in `df_2` to see if both:

- The names match
- The value in df_1, column 1 is within the range of the two values in df_2

Hits:

`foo 5`

The code below so far:

```
for row in df_1.iterrows():
    mat_idx = (df_2.iloc[:,0] == row[1][1]) & (df_2.iloc[:,1] <= row[1][2]) & (df_2.iloc[:,2] >= row[1][2])
```

This works but is not fully vectorized, I would like to go without iterating through df_1, especially for << row `DataFrames`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `df_1.columns=['name', 'value']` and `df_2.columns=['name', 'value1', 'value2]`, you could:

```
combined = df_2.merge(df_1, on='name', how='left')
keep = combined[(combined.value1<=combined.value) & (combined.value2>=combined.value)]
```